# How would you make this lacquered texture on aluminium material?

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders

I am still kind of new to Blender, and would like a bit of guidance. I've got one of the models done, but I didn't get the texture right. The panel is made of aluminium and then lacquered for the gloss.

This is what I want to achieve:
[image]
[image]

This is what I got:
[image]

I used only the Principled BSDF Shader—pumped up the Clearcoat for that lacquer effect, but it doesn't feel the same as in real life shot.

What part am I missing? Better lighting?

Comment: Be aware,  you can pump clearcoat up above 1. Type in, say, 20, and give it some roughness over a more glossy metal base? You should certainly be previewing in a suitable HDR environment.

Comment: Yes, definitely use an HDRi for fine tuning shiny materials. Also, the aluminum may be slightly anisotropic.

Comment: @RobinBetts wow, thank you for that tip, I will experiment with it and report back. Also, more glossy metal base—did you mean less rough base? Since it's metallic, doesn't that make it glossy? Just want to clarify. =)

Comment: @HISEROD good point on anisotropic. I added some of it later, but it would distort at the center point of the mass—it would look like a spiral galaxy of sorts, with obvious center point. How would you modify it so it looks more natural?

Comment: @DeliciousBacon You can use UV's for the tangent https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.91/render/shader_nodes/input/tangent.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just something along these lines?

[image]

[image]

But perhaps including, as @moonboots has suggested, some small-scale noise in the clearcoat Normal.

Comment: @Delicious Bacon .. (My understanding only) ..  Metalness affects color contributions, not roughness .. it removes the diffuse contribution of the base color, and uses that instead to tint an entirely specular color, reflected from the environment. Roughness simulates microfacets, telling us _which bits_ of the environment to reflect, from directions more or less  scattered around the normal. But .. oops, I should have taken a harder look a the the effect of IOR, especially on the contrast between direct and raking angles. Check that out.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look much more complicated than a metallic material. Maybe you need to use a bit of *Noise* into the *Roughness* value to make it look more natural (a mix of grains and bigger spots. If you want to give it anisotropic, as it doesn't work in Eevee, just stretch the small *Noise* on one axis):

[image]

[image]